# General solution of coupled oscillators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Suppose i have a system of coupled oscillators: $\ddot{\phi}_i = \sum_j M_{ij}\phi_j $. This is equivalent to the Matrix differential equation:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot{\phi}_1\\
 \vdots \\ 
\dot{\phi}_N \\ 
\dot{v}_1 \\ 
\vdots\\ 
\dot{v}_N\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 && \mathbb{I}\\ M && 0\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \phi_1 \\ \vdots \\ \phi_N \\ v_1 \\ \vdots\\ v_N\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\dot{v}_i = \ddot{\phi}_i$, right?

I know from diagonalization the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$. How are they linked to the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 && \mathbb{I}\\ M && 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$? Therefore, how do I find the solutions $\phi_i$ based on the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can diagonalize the symmetric matrix *M*, to
$$M_{ij} \mapsto D_{ij}= \lambda_i \delta_{ij} \leadsto \\
D=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1&...&0  \\
   0&  \ddots&0    \\
 0& ...&\lambda_N \end{pmatrix} ~~~~ \leadsto ~~~~
 \ddot{\varphi}_i = \lambda _i \varphi_i,     
$$
you already have the solutions! (Negative semidefinite eigenvalues.)

In phase space, you have $\dot \varphi_i = u_i$, so that $\dot u_i=\ddot \varphi_i$ $\implies \ddot u_i= \lambda_i u_i$ , and
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot{\varphi}_1\\
 \vdots \\ 
\dot{\varphi}_N \\ 
\dot{u}_1 \\ 
\vdots\\ 
\dot{u}_N\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 && \mathbb{I}\\ D && 0\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \varphi_1 \\ \vdots \\ \varphi_N \\ u_1 \\ \vdots\\ u_N\\ \end{pmatrix}.
$$

All you now need is the vanishing of the determinant of the block matrix, all of whose blocks mutually commute,
$$
 \det \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda \mathbb{I}   && \mathbb{I}\\ D && -\lambda \mathbb{I}  \\ \end{pmatrix} = \det (\lambda ^2 \mathbb{I}- D)=0.
$$
so the 2*N* eigenvalues of your (non-symmetric!) $2N\times 2N$ matrix are $\pm\sqrt{\lambda_1}$,
...,  $\pm\sqrt{\lambda_N}$.

Leaving the eigenvectors to you...  Check everything for *N*=2. Recall, for *N* =1, the eigenvectors $(1,\pm \sqrt \lambda_1  )^T$.